# A special case of Dirichlet series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, divergent-series, trigonometric-series

I have this series:

$$ \sum_{\ell = 1}^{+ \infty} e^{-t \ \ell^2} \sin{(k\ell)} = f(k, t) $$

where $ t \in [0,\infty]$,  $ k \in [0,2\pi]. $

I tried to transform the sine to exponential but whitout result.
This series is  quite similar to  third theta Jacobi  elliptic function.

For details check [this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_567.htm) page $\sim $ 575